# Present viewcontroller from custom toolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation

In my app i'm using the same bottom toolbar many times. So i created new UITollbar class which contain 4 UIBarButtonItems. How to code them for presenting another viewcontroller? I don't want do this every time, when i creating new view controller, so i prefer to do this once and use this class for every same tooolbars.
For example, this is my action for all of buttons:

```
- (void)actionButtonTapped:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem {

    switch (barButtonItem.tag) {
        case BacklogButton:
            break;

        case MyTicketsButton:
            break;

        case FilterButton:
            break;

        case ProjectsButton:
            break;
    }
}
```

It works nice, but for using presentViewController i must be in UIViewController class. I need your help.

UPD.
I wrote a little more code for you guys for explanation my problem.

```
- (void)actionButtonTapped:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem {

    switch (barButtonItem.tag) {
        case BacklogButton:
            [self presentViewControllerFromStoryBoardName:@"TRBacklogViewController"];
            break;

        case MyTicketsButton:
            [self presentViewControllerFromStoryBoardName:@"TRMyTicketsViewController"];
            break;

        case FilterButton:
            [self presentViewControllerFromStoryBoardName:@"TRFilterViewController"];
            break;

        case ProjectsButton:
            [self presentViewControllerFromStoryBoardName:@"TRProjectsViewController"];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)presentViewControllerFromStoryBoardName:(NSString*)storyboardName {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:[self viewControlerFromStoribordName:storyboardName] animated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}

- (UIViewController*)viewControlerFromStoribordName:(NSString*)storyboardName {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
    return (UIViewController*)[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
}
```

The problem is - i cant do that more than one time. Other clicks on buttons fails with error:"Attempt to present `<UINavigationController: 0x7ab0cc00>` on `<UINavigationController: 0x7c304600>` whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" Are there any ways to use pushViewController?

Comment: put your working code for present .

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to present a vc, you can do this base on the window's rootvc.

```
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:^{
    }];
```

I hope to help you!

Comment: Yes, it works, but only one time. When i click on the buttons again i get error: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7ab0cc00> on <UINavigationController: 0x7c304600> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   UIViewController *vc = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];

 [[vc presentedViewController] ? vc.presentedViewController : vc presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, I hope this will help you.

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NameOfYourStoryBoard" bundle:nil];
YourViewController *yourVC =  [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerIdentifier"];
[self presentViewController:yourVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: [self presentViewController:yourVC animated:YES completion:nil] - "self" means you are in viewController class. I'm not. I'm in UIToolBar class.

Comment: May this Link help you [link]  (http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-avoid-whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy-error-when-presenting-a-uiviewcontroller/)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code.

```
- (void)actionButtonTapped:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem {

    switch (barButtonItem.tag) {
    case BacklogButton:
        [self presentViewControllerFromStoryBoardName:@"TRBacklogViewController"];
   // @"TRBacklogViewController" I think its your View controller Identifier not a storyboard name
        break;

    case MyTicketsButton:
        [self presentViewControllerFromStoryBoardName:@"TRMyTicketsViewController"];
        break;

    case FilterButton:
        [self presentViewControllerFromStoryBoardName:@"TRFilterViewController"];
        break;

    case ProjectsButton:
        [self presentViewControllerFromStoryBoardName:@"TRProjectsViewController"];
        break;
    }
}

- (void)presentViewControllerFromStoryBoardName:(NSString*)storyboardName {

[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:[self viewControlerFromStoribordName:storyboardName] animated:YES completion:^{
  }];
}

 - (UIViewController*)viewControlerFromStoribordName:(NSString*)storyboardName {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
// May be "Main" is your storyboard name
     return (UIViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardName];
  // Use object name "viewcontrollerIdentifier" instead of "storyboardName"

 }
```

Comment: TRBacklogViewController, TRMyTicketsViewController etc. - storyboard name. I have different storyboards exept Main.